# Telegram Messenger on a Google Voice number

Tags: google-voice, telegram

[Telegram Messenger](https://telegram.org/) used to work with my Google Voice number. I logged out last week from Telegram, and can't login again.

Usually, when you want to login to Telegram, it asks you for your phone number, and Telegram sends you a text message with an activation code, but when I login with my Google Voice number I'm not getting any SMS.

Is it Google that rejects the SMS, or is it a new limitation from Telegram? Is there any workaround how to get Telegram on a Google Voice phone number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and I asked Telegram support. They told me they only allow Real mobile numbers from now on (no more VoIP). But they helped me to login with my Google Voice number and migrate to a real number.

They also told me that pre-registered VoIP numbers should work again with the next update.

Up to you to contact them in order to change the account, or wait till the next update.

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to sign up with my Google Voice account. Maybe they're changing their policy?

Comment: Is it still working for you? Did you had any problems? If it's working, I'd appreciate if you could extend your answer with more details, from what you know and experienced

Comment: Based on what @Ric said, it might just be that my VoIP number works because it was preregistered. Regardless, I have a Google Voice number and it works just fine logging in to Telegram.